# An objective-c variable being assigned a value from a mutable array element is not being correctly assigned a type

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a situation I can’t explain why is happening, can’t fix it, and can’t figure a work around for it. I have a mutable object array that holds a variable number of objects. Each object is either a string file name or a URL of a web location. I have another mutable array of integer objects that identifies the type of object at a particular index in the first array, either a 0 for string file name, or a 1 for a URL. Now, I need to access and use the elements in the first array. I index the objects and select an object with: `myObject = [ArrayName objectAtIndex:index]`. Monitoring the execution of this line of code reveals that `myObject` becomes a URL type object even if it has been defined as an `NSString`. If I attempt to use `myObject` as a string it throws an execution error saying `myObject` is a URL.

I’ve tried typedefing `myObject` as a string but it won’t take. Conversely if I attempt to convert `myObject` to a string using `NSURL`’s `URLWithString` or `NSString`’s `stringWithContentsOfURL: encoding:error:` which failed when using myObject as a URL. So I’m stuck, one set of methods thinks its another type of object, the other type of methods thinks its the other type of object. Where the debugger gets the ides that the string object is a URL I have no idea. Other questions don't exactly address this situation.
Any ideas or work arounds would be welcome.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you have an NSArray like this (there's no important difference here between NSArray and NSMutableArray for this question):

```
NSArray *array = @[
    @"This is a string",
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://stackoverflow.com"],
];
```

Each element may be a different type. So when fetching elements, the only type you can really use is `id` ("some object"):

```
id item = array[0];
```

Now you need to figure out what type it is. You can do that with `-isKindOfClass:`. For example:

```
if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    // Since it's known to be an NSString, assign it a type to improve type-safety.
    // This way the compiler will provide warnings if incorrect methods are called.
    NSString *string = item;
    NSLog(@"This is a string with length: %lu", (unsigned long)[string length]);
} else if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]]) {
    NSURL *url = item;
    NSLog(@"This is a URL with absoluteString: %@", [url absoluteString]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Unexpected type found in array: %@", [item class]);
}
```

If you write something like `NSString *item = array[0]`, Objective-C will assume you know for certain that the element is an NSString. That does not *make* it an NSString. If you're wrong, and you send a message that NSString doesn't respond to, the program will crash.

Generally speaking, multi-type (heterogeneous) arrays are a bad idea. The compiler relies on the programmer to do everything correctly, and can't help very much. But in some cases they're extremely useful, and a powerful feature of Objective-C.

You should strongly avoid having a separate array that keeps track of the types. That's just begging to be out of sync and cause problems.

Comment: Oh thank you Rob! I didn't know you could assign a class like that, I'll try it. I agree that the multi-type array was a bad idea but I could not figure out any other way to accomplish the task without it because the array at some point will be sorted based on the string file name or a name given to the URL. I've struggled with this for several days and could not figure out why the compiler thought the string was a URL when the object never was an URL. Thanks so much for the instruction.

Comment: I'm not completely certain what you're building, so this may not help, but note that Cocoa encourages you to use NSURL for local file paths, not just for network calls. So you can use NSURL for both, if that's what's giving you trouble (and this is the preferred approach). You can distinguish file URLs using `-isFileURL`, if needed.